# picture file color bit reverse engineering

Tags: c++, file, format, reverse-engineering, image

I am trying to reverse engineer a folder of many .spr sprite file . I am trying to retrieve the images stored in them
I tried opening it up with a hex editor and am trying to figure out its image height and width, and its offset to the pixelarray.

8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 8A 86 82 86

this is part of the hex info.

Qn1) It seems to me that 2 bytes consist of 1 pixel, what kind of bit type is it ?Is it a 16bit ,24bit etc

Qn2 )Anyone knows how i can figure out which byte represent the  height and width of the image?

Much appreciated for your help.

http://www.mediafire.com/?ccr180mpocz497z,tcia3h233hx6uhu,f4seeq7qe4jsg2p,5l8cdqeysrt5faf

Comment: Maybe the sprite doesn't contain a header and is asumed to have a fixed size f.e. 64x64. You can tell this if all .spr files have the same filesize. If you can't figure it out, put a few files online somewhere.

Comment: So far i only figure out at memory position 00000028 to 000002B contains the number of image in the file

Comment: What program uses these files?

Comment: It's definitely got a file header.  No magic number, though, which is a hanging offense.

Comment: It belongs to a favourite game of mine which shut down long ago.I hope i can retrieve some of the image out
I have tried opening it with different image editor on the net  but to no avail

Comment: Is it openGL game? if yes you can try gDebugger and save textures that in GPU memory

Comment: Does this .SPR definition match your files?  http://www.wotsit.org/download.asp?f=spr_form&sc=391524009

Comment: If you don't know which algorithm or compression it uses it is hard to reverse it. You could try gDebugger which was mentioned before, or you can write a program which reads the files binary and tries to set everything in colors, and then have dynamic parameters for you to try. so amount of bytes per color, width.height settings. maybe use preset settings. then load a file (and render it to a previewer) mess around with the preview settings until you get lucky..
If it has compression algorithms you are screwed though

Comment: and what is your favourite game? :)